# Difficulty understanding a method parameter type in objective c language

Tags: objective-c, protocols

What does `id<DQNetworkDelegate>` as a method parameter mean where `DQNetowrkDelegate` is a protocol in Objective-C language?

Comment: Update your question with the actual code you are asking about.

Comment: Updated the question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That parameter means it accepts any object (`id`) that happens to conform to the specified protocol (`DQNetworkDelegate`).

Answer (score 1):

The `id` type is the equivalent of Swift's `AnyObject` type, if you know Swift. It is an anonymous pointer to an object. You know that it follows Objective-C message passing conventions and uses Cocoa memory management, but that's all you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

**id** means any object type.
**id < DQNetowrkDelegate >** means any object that conforms to the protocol DQNetworkDelegate can be passed as parameter to this method.